# NetSuite: how to get or set a value for an OtherCustomField through SuiteTalk SOAP API

Tags: netsuite, suitetalk

In the NetSuite Customization UI, I've defined an "Other Custom Field" which applies to Address.  I've edited a Customer's Address and specified a value for this custom field.  When I use a SuiteTalk SOAP request to "get" this Customer, the response includes all of the customer's data, including all of the address fields, but there's nothing that corresponds to the custom field's value for this address.  This makes some sense since there's no "customFieldList" field to reference custom field values on an Address, as there is on the Customer itself and many other types of records.  So how can I get or set the value of an "otherCustomField" for a particular record that it applies to (a particular Address in this case)?  I've searched the NetSuite documentation, the support knowledge base and the internet, and so far, no luck.

And, yes, I already know how to get the metadata for the custom field itself using getCustomizationId and get/getList.  But I need data, not metadata.

Comment: The problem was that I was using the 2014.1 version of the WSDL, where the address did not include a customFieldList.  That was added in a later version of the WSDL.

Comment: I'd also like to add some info about interpreting the metadata returned by getCustomizationId for type="otherCustomField".  Each record includes a section like this which shows the record type the field applies to:
`
                    <setupCustom:recType internalId="-289" ...>
                        <platformCore:name>Address</platformCore:name>
                    </setupCustom:recType>
`
To get the metadata about all of the available recTypes (including their internalIds), use the getSelectValue operation with recordType=otherCustomField and field=recType.